# How to remove bright spot on screen in LM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Linux Mint 20.3

With no known hardware or software changes, I suddenly have a bright area on any app window I open up, but it is not there if no windows are open and only the background (slideshow of image collection) is showing.

If I turn off the slideshow and select no background and black color only, no spot appears. But if any window is opened, suddenly the spot appears, always in the same position and it never moves even if I move a window around. If I grab the top border of a window and move any edge of the window away from the bright spot, the spot disappears.

Tried a complete power off reboot, no joy.

The spot is not a single pixel or a sharply defined area, but more like the sun, bright in the middle and gradually dimming after perhaps 50-75 pixels or so.

I am at a loss on this one so before I reinstall LM, thought I would see if anyone has any ideas.

Monty

Comment: Try disabling the compositor or window effects (under Desktop Settings or Appearance or similar.)

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try. There is a "Windows Effects" setting, which I disabled along with ALL Desktop and other effects settings. Then rebooted. I still have the spot.

Comment: Super weird. Before reinstalling I would try booting from a live CD or USB of a different OS. If it's still there then it must be a hardware issue somehow.

Comment: You are correct. I had a Windoze dual boot setup I had forgotten about and booted into it. The problem is still there. I also removed all HDMI inputs (no white spot) and went into the TV's menu and it was there also, so definitely a TV problem of some sort. What fooled me was when I booted, I expected the white spot to show if it was a hardware issue, but in the boot menus, it was all clear. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Nick Matteo provided the tip to confirm it was a hardware issue with the TV/Monitor, not the OS. The white spot was not there during the DOS boot/bios screens, which initially fooled me into discounting a hardware issue. So the problem only shows up when there is a video feed other than low res boot screens.